# How can I add static files without using Djstatic and Whitenoise?

Tags: python, django, heroku, static

I was trying to use Whitenoise and Djstatic to server Django static files on Heroku to me I feel they are quite complicated does anyone have an alternative

Comment: I haven't heard of Djstatic before, but its [README](https://github.com/heroku-python/dj-static/blob/master/README.rst) suggests using Whitenoise instead. Enabling Whitenoise can be as easy as adding one line to `MIDDLEWARE`, so I'm not sure why you feels it's complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it that always works for me.

1. Install `gunicorn` with the command:

> pip install gunicorn

2. Ensure you have a Procfile with the following line:

> `web: gunicorn project_name.wsgi`.

This is to instruct Heroku on how to start your server.

3. Install the `python_django` module with the command:

> pip install django-heroku

4. In your `app/settings.py` ensure to import the `python-django` module at the top

```
import django_heroku 

# Add the following line at the bottom

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Your app should be ready to deploy now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [django-heroku](https://pypi.org/project/django-heroku/) module.
The module handles static files, configures database settings, static files, allowed hosts etc.

To use it in your application just: `pip install django-heroku`

Comment: I just tried it out, its actually easy 2 lines of code, man thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any better way to do it apart from using whitenoise maybe you could take a look at this hope it makes using Whitenoise a breeze (Here's [a link](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html)!